# jQuery with hide and show

Tags: jquery

I dont get how to tell my function that if i click again on the open tabs, close and stop animation. My problem right now is my tab close, and redo to .show() action. Here a fiddle for you to see; http://jsfiddle.net/X2dsS/1/

```
$('.lst-cours .extrainfo').hide()
$('.lst-cours').click(function(){
    $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').hide("slow")
    $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').removeClass("active")
    $(this).children().find('.extrainfo').show("slow").addClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some small changes
Please see the code below:

```
    $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').hide()
$('.lst-cours').click(function(){
    if($(this).children().find('.extrainfo').is(":visible"))
    {
        $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').hide("slow");
        $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').removeClass("active");
    }
    else
    {
        $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').hide("slow");
        $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').removeClass("active");
    $(this).children().find('.extrainfo').show("slow").addClass('active');
   }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

So, all in all, you need to add an if statement to check the class, but you need to do this before you do any hiding and showing. Then save that value. The following is the code that works well, *including* an extra `stop` command that will prevent the nimation from repeating over and over.

```
$('.lst-cours').click(function(){
    var clickElement = $(this).children().find('.extrainfo');
    var hideOnly = clickElement.hasClass("active");

    $('.lst-cours .extrainfo').stop();
    $('.lst-cours .extrainfo.active').hide("slow");
    $('.lst-cours .extrainfo.active').removeClass("active");        

    if (!hideOnly){
        clickElement.show("slow").addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**See the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqtp/4/

Comment: The problem with that, is if i click on another tab when one is open, it close the tab but dont open the other one we have click.

Comment: @goregrind The final solution here should work well and has a stop command to make sure the animation doesn't repeat. Best of luck!